# Let be $G$ a group and $a,b \in G$. Prove that $ (ab) ^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof

I have a proof:

Let $x$ the inverse of $ab$ so $$ x(ab) = 1 $$ $$ xa = b^{-1 }$$ $$ x = b^{-1 }a^{-1} $$

Some of you know another way to do it? Something like: $$ (ab)^{-1} = \cdots =\cdots=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: The inverse of an element is unique. Therefore, it's enough to check that
$$
(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = (b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab) = 1.
$$

Comment: In fact, it is sufficient to check that it is a left (or right) inverse of $ab$, @rolandcyp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
(ab)^{-1}
=
&
(ab)^{-1}e
\\
=
&
(ab)^{-1}[aa^{-1}]
\\
=
&
(ab)^{-1}\big[(ae)a^{-1}\big]
\\
=
&
(ab)^{-1}\Big[\big(a[bb^{-1}]\big)a^{-1}\Big]
\\
=
&
(ab)^{-1}\Big[([ab]b^{-1})a^{-1}\Big]
\\
=
&
(ab)^{-1}\Big[[ab]\big(b^{-1}a^{-1}\big)\Big]
\\
=
&
\Big[(ab)^{-1}[ab]\Big]\big(b^{-1}a^{-1}\big)
\\
=
&
e\big(b^{-1}a^{-1}\big)
\\
=
&
b^{-1}a^{-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$$(ab)^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}((ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}))=((ab)^{-1}(ab))(b^{-1}a^{-1})=b^{-1}a^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$ab.b^{-1}a^{-1}=a.a^{-1}=1$

And $b^{-1}a^{-1}.ab=b^{-1}.b=1$

Thus $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$